# Printing dissasembly information in Cuda-gdb

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

I would like to print information from cuda disassembly.

I am able to print registers in cuda using info registers R1 for example however I am not able to figure out how to print  `c[0x0][0x20]` in  (`MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20]`) or deferenced `[R13+0x9f]`  in (`STL.U8 [R13+0x9f], RZ`)

Answer (score 2):

When using gdb or cuda-gdb you can use the disass command to disassemble the current code or code at a specific location.

```
cuda-gdb a.out
```

debug the program

```
b main
```

break in main

```
r
```

run the program, when the breakpoint is hit

```
 disass
```

disassemble the following code at the breakpoint